# How do you add scripts to custom buttons on rows in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, client, jqgrid

I am trying to handle the click of custom button in a jqgrid. I have the buttons showing up, but when they are clicked, my function does not run. If I click a button outside the jqgrid, the script runs. Does jqgrid consume the button click? Not sure what I am missing or not understanding. Here is the grid. The reason I am not reloading the entire grid is there is too much processing on the server, and need to manually remove the row on the client once the editurl processes the "send." `See: $(".sendbuttons").click(function(){`

...

```
        <style type="text/css">
        .sendbuttons {
            height:19px;
            width:60px;
            color:red;
        }
    </style>

    <script language="javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var last_row;
        jQuery("#gridlist").jqGrid({
            url:'manual_responses.php',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['ID','Image','Keyword','send Found','Proposed send',''],
            colModel:[
                {name:'item_id', index:'item_id', width:45, editable:false, hidden:true},
                {name:'image', index:'image', width:45},
                {name:'keyword',index:'keyword', width:100, editable: false},
                {name:'item_found',index:'item_found', width:130, editable: false},
                {name:'proposed_send',index:'proposed_send', width:130, editable: true, edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"37"}},
                {name:'options',index:'options',width:40,editable: false}
            ],
            rowNum:40,
            rowList:[20,40,60],
            imgpath: 'css/themes/sand/images',
            sortname: 'keyword',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption:"Proposed sends",
            onSelectRow: function(item_id){
                if(item_id && item_id!==last_row){
                    jQuery("#gridlist").restoreRow(last_row);
                    jQuery("#gridlist").editRow(item_id,true);
                    last_row=item_id;
                }
            },
            loadComplete: function(){ 
                //alert('ok, loadComplete running');
                var ids = jQuery("#gridlist").getDataIDs(); 
                for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){ 
                    var cl = ids[i];
                    send = "<input class='sendbuttons' id='tbuttonSend"+cl+"' type='button' value='Send' /><br />"; 
                    clear = "<input class='sendbuttons' id='tbuttonClear"+cl+"' type='button' value='Send' /><br />"; 
                    jQuery("#gridlist").setRowData(ids[i],{options:send+clear}) 
                } 
            }, 
            editurl: "item_send.php",
            height:400,
            width:796,
            reloadAfterSubmit:false
        }).navGrid('#pager2',{edit:true,add:false,del:false });

        $(".sendbuttons").click(function(){
            alert("got to 1");
        });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="gridlist" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
    <div id="pager2" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>

    <input type='button' class='sendbuttons' id='323423x' value='go:'/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am working to answer this myself, and I think I am headed in the right direction. I modified my button click event to call the saveRow function, passing it a succesfunc function and url. Unfortunately the url seems to be mis-interpreted...in Firebug|Console it says item_send not defined. Are there limitations on what the url should look like? my url is item_send.php.

send = "<input name='send' class='tweetbuttons' id='tbuttonSend"+cl+"' type='button' value='Send' onclick=jQuery('#list2').saveRow("+cl+",function(){alert('madeithere')},item_send.php); /><br />";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is apparent that the click event,

```
$(".sendbuttons").click(function(){
     alert("got to 1");
});
```

never fires because the click of the row consumes it. You can, however, put in your own onclick code in the button.

```
send = "<input name='send' class='tweetbuttons' id='tbuttonSend"+cl+
       "' type='button' value='Send' 
       onclick=jQuery('#list2').saveRow("+cl+",function(){alert('made it here')},item_send); /><br />";
```

As discussed in my comment, I can call the saveRow function with any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$(".sendbuttons").click(function(){
     alert("got to 1");
});
```

in gridComplete callback and it fires.

```
loadComplete: function(){ 
    //alert('ok, loadComplete running');
    var ids = jQuery("#gridlist").getDataIDs();
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
        var cl = ids[i];
        send = "<input class='sendbuttons' id='tbuttonSend"+cl+"' type='button' value='Send' /><br />";
        clear = "<input class='sendbuttons' id='tbuttonClear"+cl+"' type='button' value='Send' /><br />";
        jQuery("#gridlist").setRowData(ids[i],{options:send+clear})
 }
    $(".sendbuttons").click(function(){
        alert("got to 1");
    });
},
```