# Adding a custom button in row in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid, client

I want to make a simple table that contains a custom button in a row.  When the button is pushed, I want to pop up an 'alert' box.   I have read some posts on this, for example:
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384685/how-do-you-add-scripts-to-custom-buttons-on-rows-in-jqgrid)
and
[this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299479/adding-a-button-to-a-row-in-jqgrid), and I don't understand why my code is not working.  The buttons are drawn, but pushing them has no effect.

I have three attempts described here.

Version 1.   The button click never fires:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#simpletable").jqGrid({
         datatype: "local",
        colNames:['A','B','Status'],
        colModel:[
        {name:'A',index:'A'},
        {name:'B',index:'B'},
        {name:'status',index:status}
    ],
        data:[ 
        {'A':2,'B':100,'status':"<button  onclick=\"jQuery('#simpletable').saveRow('1', function(){alert('you are in')});\" >in</button>"},
        {'A':1,'B':200,'status':"<button onclick=\"jQuery('#simpletable').saveRow('2', function(){alert('you are in')});\" >in</button>"},
        ],
        caption: "Demo of Custom Clickable Button in Row",
        viewrecords:true,
        editurl:'clientArray',
    });

   });
```

Html Code:

```
<table id="simpletable"></table>
```

EDIT 8/2/12 --  I've learned some things since my original post and here I describe two more attempts.

Version 2:  I use onCellSelect.   This works, but it would not allow me to put more than one button in a cell.    Additionally, I made the code nicer by using the format option suggested by one of the comments to this post.

```
function status_button_maker_v2(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    return "<button class=\"ver2_statusbutton\">"+cellvalue+"</button>"
};

jQuery("#simpletablev2").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:['A','B','Status'],
    colModel:[
    {name:'A',index:'A'},
    {name:'B',index:'B'},
    {name:'status',index:status,editable:true,formatter:status_button_maker_v2}
    ],
        data:[ 
    {'A':2,'B':100,'status':"In"},
    {'A':1,'B':200,'status':"Out"}
        ],

    onCellSelect:function(rowid,icol,cellcontent,e){
    if (icol==2){

        alert('My value in column A is: '+$("#simpletablev2").getRowData(rowid)['A']);
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    },

    caption: "Demo of Custom Clickable Button in Row, ver 2",
    viewrecords:true,
});  //end simpletablev2
```

Markup:

```
<style>.ver2_statusbutton { color:blue;} </style>
<h3>simple table, ver 2:</h3>
<table id="simpletablev2"></table>
```

Version 3:   I tried to use the solution to [w4ik's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774018/call-a-function-from-a-button-that-is-created-during-jqgrids-gridcomplete-event?answertab=active#tab-top), using ".on" instead of deprecated ".live".   This causes the button click to fire, but I don't know how to retrieve the rowid.  w4ik also struggled with this, and he posted that he worked it out, but not how he did it.   I can get the last row selected, but this will always refer to the previous row selected because the button is taking priority.

I would prefer this solution if I could get it to work.

```
jQuery("#simpletablev3").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:['A','B','Status'],
    colModel:[
    {name:'A',index:'A'},
    {name:'B',index:'B'},
    {name:'status',index:status,editable:true,formatter:status_button_maker_v3}
    ],
        data:[ 
    {'A':2,'B':100,'status':"In"},
    {'A':1,'B':200,'status':"Out"}
        ],
    caption: "Demo of Custom Clickable Button in Row, ver 3",
    viewrecords:true,
    onSelectRow: function(){},
    gridComplete: function(){}
});  //end simpletablev3


$(".ver3_statusbutton").on(
    {
    click: function(){
        //how to get the row id?  the following does not work
        //var rowid = $("#simpletablev3").attr('rowid'); 
        //
        //it also does not work to get the selected row
        //   this is always one click behind:
        //$("#simpletablev3").trigger("reloadGrid");
        rowid = $("#simpletablev3").getGridParam('selrow');
        alert("button pushed! rowid = "+rowid);
    }
    });
```

Markup:

```
 <style>.ver3_statusbutton {    color:red;} </style>
 <h3>simple table, ver 3:</h3>
 <table id="simpletablev3"></table>
```

In summary, I'm struggling with the issue of getting my button to be pushed *at the right time*.  In version 1, the row gets selected and the button never gets pushed.  Version 2 does not use the "button" at all -- It just handles the cell click.  Verion 3 gets the button click before the row select (wrong order).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: better to use click() event of jquery in such case, made jsfiddle and I'll show you how

Comment: You do not need to add the markup to your data, you can instead use a customFormatter for the column to generate the button with your status value. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use action formatter here with each row and make edit and delete button as false in formatOptions like this:

```
formatoptions: {editbutton:false,delbutton:false}}
```

And follow these two demos:

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm

http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestSamle/Admin1.htm

And on click event of these custom buttons show your alert:

**EDIT**

```
var getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {

                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;

                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {

                    if (cm[i].name === columnName) {

                        return i; // return the index

                    }

                }

                return -1;

            },

function () {

                var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'act');

                $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")

                    .each(function() {

                        $("<div>", {

                            title: "Custom",

                            mouseover: function() {

                                $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');

                            },

                            mouseout: function() {

                                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');

                            },

                            click: function(e) {

                                alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis="+

                                    $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") +" !");

                            }

                        }

                      ).css({"margin-right": "5px", float: "left", cursor: "pointer"})

                       .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom")

                       .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>')

                       .prependTo($(this).children("div"));

                });

            }
```

If you check this code, I'm trying to find out index value by giving column name as 'act', you can get index on any other column by giving a different column name.

```
var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'Demo'); and the rest of the code will be same for you. //demo is the column name where u want to add custom button
```

and write your click event for this button.

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks for your repsponse.  I studied your code.   If I understand correctly, your code shows how to customize the action formatters.   But I want to make my own button - maybe even a table full of buttons in each cell.  I don't undertand how to use your ideas to do that.  Is it possible?  (I know that I have a 'saveRow' in there -- I don't think it needs to be there -- I got it from copying code in another SO post.)

Comment: Buddy, check these links, i'm using a custom button with action formatter buttons, by giving is of action column link...same way you can give id if other columns and add custom button with them.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I now understand better what your code is doing, and I got this to work with my custom button.   This is exactly what I was looking for!