# insert a datepicker in column of jqgrid (without jquery datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I'm trying to insert a datepicker in a column of jqgrid, but the datepicker won't show. I don't why, but my question is if I can (and if it's possible how to) insert another datepicker (non jquery) or some other datepicker.

Or maybe you can help me to insert a jquery datepicker correctly. This is my code.

```
container.jqGrid({
    width: 440,
    height: 260,
    colNames:[ "Id", "Combustible", "Factor", "Fecha Inicio", "Fecha Fin", "Borrar"],
    colModel : [
        {name: 'idproduct', index: 'idproduct', width: 25, sortable: false, align: 'center', editable: true, editoptions:{maxlength:5}},
        {name: 'fuel',  index : 'fuel',  width : 60,    sortable: false, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype:"select", editoptions:{value:"1:Magna;2:Premium;3:Diesel"} },
        {name: 'factor', index : 'factor',  width : 30, sortable: false, align: 'center'  , editable: true, editoptions:{maxlength:5} },
        {name: 'dateStart', index : 'dateStart',  width : 60,   sortable: false, align: 'right', editable: true, editoptions: { size: 20, maxlengh: 10,
                dataInit: function(element) 
                         { $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',        constrainInput: false, showOn: 'button', buttonText: '...' });
                         } } 
        },

        {name: 'dateEnd', index : 'dateEnd',  width : 60,   sortable : false, align: 'right', editable:true, 
         editrules: { date: true, minValue: 0 }, datefmt: 'yy-mm-dd' },
        {name: 'delButton',  index: 'delButton',  width: 40,  sortable: false, align: 'center'}
    ],
    pager: containerPager, 
    pgbuttons: false, 
    pginput:false,
    viewrecords: false,
    rowNum: 0,
    rowList: 0,
    pgtext: "",
    caption: "Promociones Hora Feliz",
    loadGrid: true,
    loadComplete: function()
    {
        var ids = container.getDataIDs();
        for(var i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
        {
            var cl = ids[i];
            delButton = "<center><div class=\"ui-state-error-text ui-corner-all \" style=\"height:16px; width:16px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer; \" " +
                " title=\"Borrar Registro\" onclick=\"$(\'#" + container.attr("id") +"\').delRowData('"+cl+"');\">"+
                "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close\" style=\"float: left; margin-right: .3em;\"></span>"+
                "</div></center>"
            container.setRowData( ids[i], { delButton:delButton } );
        }
    },

    afterEditCell: function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol) {
        $("#" + iRow + "_factor").numericFloat();
        $("#" + iRow + "_idproduct").numericFloat();
    },

    afterSaveCell: function(rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol)
    { 
        var rangesPoints = [];  
        var ids = container.getDataIDs();
        $.each(ids,function(id,value){
            var retx = container.getRowData( value +"");
            var rangesPointTmp = [];
            rangesPointTmp[0] = parseInt( retx.idproduct );
            rangesPointTmp[1] = retx.fuel;
            rangesPointTmp[2] = parseFloat( retx.factor );

            rangesPointTmp[3] = retx.dateStart;
            rangesPointTmp[4] = retx.dateEnd;;

            rangesPoints.push(rangesPointTmp);
        });

    },
    onSelectRow: function(id){},
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray'
}).navGrid( containerPager.attr("id") ,{edit:false,add:false,del:false, search:false })
.toolBarButtonAdd({
    caption:"Agregar", 
    buttonimg:"ui-icon-plus",
    onClickButton: function(){
        if( ! container.getGridParam("records") )
        {
            nextId +=1;
        }
        else{
            var ids = container.getDataIDs();
            nextId = parseInt( ids[0] );
            var retx = container.getRowData( nextId +"");

            if( parseFloat(retx.factor) == 0 || parseFloat(retx.idproduct) == 0)
            {
                showErrorMessageDialog({message:"Existen datos no validos"});
                return false;
            }

            nextId +=1;
        }
        var datarow = {
            idproduct: "",
            fuel: "",
            factor: "",
            dateStart: "",
            dateEnd: "",
            delButton :"<center><div  class=\"ui-state-error-text\"  style=\"height:16px; width:16px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer; \" " +
                " title=\"Borrar Registro\" onclick=\"$(\'#" + container.attr("id") +"\').delRowData('"+ nextId +"');\"> " +
                "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close\" style=\"float: left; margin-right: .3em;\"></span>" +
                "</div></center>"
        };
        var su=container.addRowData( nextId, datarow, 'first');
    },
    position: "last"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Filly/eZPRc/2/)** is a fiddle with the working code.

Remember the datepicker you are trying to use belongs to jQuery UI, not jQuery. So you need to include both in your project (you can download jQuery [here](http://jquery.com/download/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) here).

I also added `formatter: 'date'` in the dateStart and dateEnd columns. Make sure the `formatoptions` fits the `dateFormat` in the datepicker options.

As an extra, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744722/1924026) how to implement an action column with a delete button, in case your current button is not working and you need it (I didn't use this column in my fiddle).

Comment: hi, thank for your answer, but that files (jquery ui and jquery) are included, one detail the datepicker works correctly in html code but not in jqgrid, maybe you know how to can include other type of datepicker in jqgrid.

Comment: Did you try the code of the fiddle I made? The datepicker is working just fine in the jqGrid there, and I didn't change much of your code to make it work.

Comment: sadly not work, maybe is problem of css or jquery files (maybe the version are diferent), i try to change versions or homologate the files, thanks for your answer